# intensive data sending breaks IOCP events

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, iocp

I use `Windows IOCP` in my app for few years without any issues (permanent `TCP` communication with small messages), but recently I had to send very big application state (25k of messages, about 12Mb all together).

I use 0x2000-bytes buffers, combined with `IOCP` events: first `write` triggers `WSASend`, all other just fill the buffers. When `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` gets event, that write was completed, next buffer is sent via `WSASend`, and so on.

This is first time I use such a use-case to send so big data at once. And I noticed, that after some time `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` stops receiving events.

Here is visualization, how data from buffer is sent from IOCP callback:

```
14:16:19.894, WSASend scheduled buffer size (3005) , pendingWrite bytes 3005
14:16:20.021, WSASend scheduled buffer size (1175) , pendingWrite bytes 1175
14:16:20.276, WSASend scheduled buffer size (4652) , pendingWrite bytes 4652
14:16:20.411, WSASend scheduled buffer size (2135) , pendingWrite bytes 2135
14:16:20.604, WSASend scheduled buffer size (3366) , pendingWrite bytes 3366
14:16:20.835, WSASend scheduled buffer size (3718) , pendingWrite bytes 3718
14:16:20.943, WSASend scheduled buffer size (665)  , pendingWrite bytes 665
14:16:21.087, WSASend scheduled buffer size (2931) , pendingWrite bytes 2931
14:16:21.109, WSASend scheduled buffer size (296)  , pendingWrite bytes 296
14:16:21.109, WSASend scheduled buffer size (21)   , pendingWrite bytes 21
14:16:21.182, WSASend scheduled buffer size (380)  , pendingWrite bytes 380
14:16:21.184, WSASend scheduled buffer size (160)  , pendingWrite bytes 160
14:16:21.355, WSASend scheduled buffer size (5885) , pendingWrite bytes 5885
14:16:21.531, WSASend scheduled buffer size (8169) , pendingWrite bytes 16135 <-- here buffers start growing
14:16:21.691, WSASend scheduled buffer size (8173) , pendingWrite bytes 19727
14:16:21.692, WSASend scheduled buffer size (8176) , pendingWrite bytes 11554
```

As you can see, after some moment, pendingWrite starts growing, but it's OK, I have a lot of memory for buffering it. But after last send (at `14:16:21.692`) `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` simply does't trigger.

I tried to increase send/receive socket buffers (SO_RCVBUF/SO_SNDBUF) to 80Kb, but looks like this didn't have any effect.

I have no idea, what should I check next, `WSASend` doesn't return any error (only `ERROR_IO_PENDING` which is expected).

PS: communication is on the same PC, Windows 7 x64.

Comment: without see the code think not possible say something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly: my assumption was, that **code worked wel**l, so I guessed, that `IOCP` (or socket) settings were unsuitable for such a throughput, or maybe there are some limitations for socket buffer.

Answer: **code had race condition**, so sometime `receiver` stopped consuming data from socket, that's why `sending` socket's buffer finally reached it's limit, and `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` didn't trigger new events for socket's write callback.

Summary: `IOCP` works as expected, no extra configuration is needed.

When race was fixed, I was able to send over 150k small packets (20-200 bytes) in a moment.